# How to query on calculated column using Breeze

Tags: breeze

I have two columns in my database table (dueDate & lateMinutes).

How do I create a Where predicate that adds lateMinutes to dueDate and compares the result to a given date (aGivenDate).

eg. .where(dueDate + lateMinutes > aGivenDate)

Any idea how to do this with a Breeze query where predicate?

Any help appreciated.

Regards,

Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard query syntax supporting date arithmetic within breeze, so your best bet for this would be to use a named query with a parameter. i.e. So assuming that the name of your EntityType was say 'Schedule' something like this

- On the client

  ```
  var q = EntityQuery.from("SchedulesAfter")
    .where(...) // this can be any valid where clause for the 'Schedule' type ( or can be omitted completely if you don't need additional query restrictions.
    .withParameter( { givenDate: aGivenDate });
  ```
- On the server

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public IQueryable<Schedule> SchedulesAfter(DateTime givenDate) {
    // This needs to return a valid IQueryable 
    // You will need to find the correct EF syntax to support your query here. You may need to use an EF function here instead. 
    return ContextProvider.Context.Schedules
      .Where(s => DbFunctions.AddMinutes(s.DueDate ,s.LateMinutes) > givenDate);
  }
  ```

In effect, you are calling a custom query method on the server with a parameter and then telling the server how to implement the query using this parameter.

Comment: @Jay Traband I think `Where(s => s.DueDate + s.LateMinutes > givenDate)` should be replaced by `Where(s =>DbFunctions.AddMinutes(s.DueDate ,s.LateMinutes) > givenDate)` Assuming the LastMinutes is `int`